# Use associative Javascript arrays to populate dropdown, then fill text box

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to Javascript (but fairly proficient in php) and I'm trying to use a set of associative arrays to perform two tasks.

First: Populate a dropdown menu  (this part is working)

```
var select = document.getElementById('FName');
var options = fNames;
for(var i = 0; i < (options.length-1); i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

The 'fNames' variable is an array with a list of strings which I've taken from a php array.  I have another array, called 'fDesc' which is indexed to match the 'fNames' array. Something like this:

```
var fNames = ["aName", "bName", "cName"]
var fDesc = ["aDesc", "bDesc,", "cDesc"]
```

They're currently separate arrays, not a single multidimensional one.

How can I make "aDesc" appear in a text box when "aName" is selected from the pulldown menu?

Comment: better put `aName` as text and `aDesc` as value.

Comment: @Mritunjay this works for simple values of `fDesc` but not for complex ones. There is no need to squeeze your data through the DOM. Keeping it in-memory in JavaScript is fine.

Comment: @Halcyon I didn't get what do you mean by `complex` here. And any way I'll be having something as value.

Comment: @Mritunjay I mean _not-a-scalar_ or _easily serializable_ value, like `{foo: function () {} }`

Comment: @Halcyon ok thanks telling me, I've not thought about that, but I don't think OP need something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the for element is population less elements, you should remove the `-1` of `(options.length-1)`

Then you need to asociate a handler event for select.onchange and use index of to retrieve the index of the array.

HTML:

```
<select id='FName'></select>
<input id='AName' type='text'/>
```

JS:

```
var fNames = ["aName", "bName", "cName"];
var fDesc = ["aDesc", "bDesc,", "cDesc"];
var select = document.getElementById('FName');
var options = fNames;
for(var i = 0; i < (options.length); i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}

    select.onchange = function(){
        var textbox = document.getElementById('AName');
        textbox.value = fDesc[fNames.indexOf(select.value)];
    }
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dBtUz/

Comment: Thanks -- this is just what I needed.  And thanks for catching my "-1" in the counter.  I'd been playing with something else earlier and forgot that was in there!

Answer (score 0):

better put `aName` as text and `aDesc` as value.

HTML

```
<select id='FName' onchange='fillText()'></select>
<input id='Fdesc' type='text'/>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    var fNames = ["aName", "bName", "cName"]
    var fDesc = ["aDesc", "bDesc", "cDesc"]
    var select = document.getElementById('FName');
    for(var i = 0; i < (fNames.length); i++) {
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = fNames[i];
        el.value = fDesc[i];
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
    select.selectedIndex = -1;
}

function fillText(){
    document.getElementById('Fdesc').value = document.getElementById('FName').value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help -- this almost covered it.  I just couldn't run the function onload.  The fNames and fDesc variables aren't defined until farther down the page -- I use php to grab them from my MySQL database and manipulate them before I can plug them into a JavaScript array in the desired fashion.  But this would work if I just defined the function after the variables existed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search the index of the selected value and then you get with that index the same position in your search array.

Updated Solution also with manual fill:

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomContentLoaded);

    // data
    var fNames = ["aName", "bName", "cName"];
    var fDesc = ["aDesc", "bDesc", "cDesc"];

    function onDomContentLoaded() {

        var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        fillSelect(mySelect);

        mySelect.addEventListener('change', onSelectChange);
    }

    function fillSelect(mySelect) {
        for(var i = 0; i < (fNames.length); i++) {
            var opt = fNames[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            mySelect.appendChild(el);
        }
    }

    function onSelectChange(){

      var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

      //console.log('selected value', selectedValue);
      var selectedValueIndexInArray = fNames.indexOf(selectedValue);
      var fieldOutput = document.getElementById("output");
      fieldOutput.innerHTML = fDesc[selectedValueIndexInArray];
    }

</script>

<select id="mySelect"></select>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Working Example
http://jsfiddle.net/x92ka/4/